# StackOverflowError with @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, stack-overflow

I have a primary and a secondary class used to store the errors when saving.
Errors can be of various types and primary key is the main class and type of error.
This is the mapping of my classes:

My primary class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class FooEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")    
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "param1") 
    private String param1;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
    List<FooErrorEntity> errors;
    //getters&setters
}
```

My error class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fooerror")
public class FooErrorEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private FooErrorId id;

    @Column(name = "descripcion")
    private String description;

    //Getters&& setters
}
```

My error id class:

```
@Embeddable
public class FooErrorId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", nullable = false)      
    private FooEntity foo;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private ErrorType type;

    //getters&setters
}
```

In my controller I do checks for errors and add it to the list:

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final String saveFoo(@ModelAttribute("foo") FooEnntity foo) {

```
//My checks... and add the errors

FooErrorEntity error1 = new FooErrorEntity();
error1.setDescription("Desc1");
FooErrorId errorId1 = new FooErrorId();
errorId1.setFoo(foo);
errorId1.setType(ErrorType.ERROR3);
error1.setId(errorId1);

foo.getErrors().add(error1);

fooService.save(foo);

return "view";
```

}

If I'm editing a FooEntity with errors I have this error:

```
Hibernate: select errors0_.foo_id as foo_id3_2_0_, errors0_.type as type1_2_0_, errors0_.foo_id as foo_id3_2_1_, errors0_.type as type1_2_1_, errors0_.descripcion as descripc2_2_1_ from fooerror errors0_ where errors0_.foo_id=? Hibernate: select fooentity0_.id as id1_1_1_, fooentity0_.param1 as param2_1_1_, errors1_.foo_id as foo_id3_2_3_, errors1_.type as type1_2_3_, errors1_.foo_id as foo_id3_2_0_, errors1_.type as type1_2_0_, errors1_.descripcion as descripc2_2_0_ from foo fooentity0_ left outer join fooerror errors1_ on fooentity0_.id=errors1_.foo_id where fooentity0_.id=? .... Hibernate: select fooentity0_.id as id1_1_1_, fooentity0_.param1 as param2_1_1_, errors1_.foo_id as foo_id3_2_3_, errors1_.type as type1_2_3_, errors1_.foo_id as foo_id3_2_0_, errors1_.type as type1_2_0_, errors1_.descripcion as descripc2_2_0_ from foo fooentity0_ left outer join fooerror errors1_ on fooentity0_.id=errors1_.foo_id where fooentity0_.id=? Hibernate: select fooentity0_.id as id1_1_1_, fooentity0_.param1 as param2_1_1_, errors1_.foo_id as foo_id3_2_3_, errors1_.type as type1_2_3_, errors1_.foo_id as foo_id3_2_0_, errors1_.type as type1_2_0_, errors1_.descripcion as descripc2_2_0_ from foo fooentity0_ left outer join fooerror errors1_ on fooentity0_.id=errors1_.foo_id where fooentity0_.id=? Hibernate: select fooentity0_.id as id1_1_1_, fooentity0_.param1 as param2_1_1_, errors1_.foo_id as foo_id3_2_3_, errors1_.type as type1_2_3_, errors1_.foo_id as foo_id3_2_0_, errors1_.type as type1_2_0_, errors1_.descripcion as descripc2_2_0_ from foo fooentity0_ left outer join fooerror errors1_ on fooentity0_.id=errors1_.foo_id where fooentity0_.id=? mar 01, 2016 9:15:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [dispatcher] en el contexto con ruta [/springMVC] lanzó la excepción [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] con causa raíz java.lang.StackOverflowError    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:428)     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.getInstance(PreparedStatement.java:834)     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.clientPrepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1573)   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4591)     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4489)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)     at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1928)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1897)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)


    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)

    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)

    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)

    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2198)     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
```

and the log continues... I get infinite selects the foo table

Comment: Great, You have logged ten thousand errors, and now we are very happy to help You with all of them. But You should wait ten thousand next days since we read it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a Derived Identity.

`FooEntity.errors` should be "mapped by" `foo`:

```
public class FooEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
    List<FooErrorEntity> errors;
    ...
}
```

`FooErrorEntity`'s relation `foo` should be moved out of the `@EmbeddedId` and into the `@Entity` itself and it should specify a `@MapsId`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fooerror")
public class FooErrorEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private FooErrorId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", nullable = false)      
    @MapsId("fooId") // maps fooId attribute of the embedded id
    private FooEntity foo;

    @Column(name = "descripcion")
    private String description;

    ...
}
```

And `FooErrorId`'s `foo` should be replaced by a `fooId` whose type corresponds to `FooEntity`'s primary key's type:

```
@Embeddable
public class FooErrorId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer fooId; // type corresponds to FooEntity's id

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private ErrorType type;

    ...
}
```

Derived identity is discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.

Comment: This is the SOLUTION!, Works great! Thanks.

Comment: Indeed. For the most recent version of JPA, this works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like an infinite loop to me - FooEntity has a List of FooErrorEntity's that has a FooErrorId which has a FooEntry.  That's already a circular dependency.

Comment: I understand that. But because it happens in this case? I have  other bidirectional @OneToMany relationships in which I do not have this error.
How I can map the error entity if the foo entity and type of error are a unique composite key?